# How to write unit test cases for localStorage values in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, local-storage, karma-jasmine

login.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();

    //  loginStatus = 1 - redirect to search
    //  else - redirect to login
    let loginStatus = localStorage.getItem('smtLogin');
    if (loginStatus == '1') {
      this.router.navigate(['/search']);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('smtLogin', '0');
    }
  }
```

login.component.spec.ts

```
  it('it should navigate to search after user signs in', () => {
    expect(localStorage.setItem('smtLogin', '1')).toBe('1'); // set the localstorage smtLogin to '1'
    expect(localStorage.getItem('smtLogin')).toBe('1'); //get the loaclstotorage smtLogin value as'1'
    expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/search']);
  });
```

errors:

1. Argument of type '"1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected'.
2. Block-scoped variable 'expect' used before its declaration.
3. Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ [ '/search' ] ] but it was never called.

Could you please help me write a test case for this statement **this.router.navigate(['/search']);** inside the if() block on ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Argument of type '"1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected':

- This is because `expect(localStorage.setItem('smtLogin', '1')).toBe('1');` is not doing what you think. `localStorage.setItem()` returns `void`, which is not assignable to type `Expected` -> string. There is no need to expect anything, simply do `localStorage.setItem('smtLogin', '1')`

> Block-scoped variable 'expect' used before its declaration.

- This looks like an issue with imports, make sure jasmine types are properly imported.

> Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ [ '/search' ] ] but
>   it was never called.

- Looks like you're not referencing the actual router but instead only a stubbed class. Get a reference to the actual router used in your component and check if that one was called. Please read https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component for an explanation on how to do that.

On a sidenote, always use `===` when comparing values:

Use `loginStatus === '1'` instead of `loginStatus == '1'`